# DialogFragment is not shown on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

i have the following class:

```
public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                // Set Dialog Icon
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                // Set Dialog Title
                .setTitle("Alert DialogFragment")
                // Set Dialog Message
                .setMessage("Alert DialogFragment Tutorial")

                // Positive button
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something else
                    }
                })

                // Negative Button
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something else
                    }
                }).create();
    }
}
```

and the other class from which i am calling this class.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<?> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<?> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ....
    }

     ....
         ....

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        final Button btn_login = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        btn_print.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new LineupFragment();


            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    public class LineupFragment extends FragmentActivity{

        public LineupFragment() {

              MyAlertDialogFragment alert = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
              alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Alert_Dialog");
        }

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }

    }
}
```

When i click on button then it gives the force close error.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.novum.ideal, PID: 9408
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1387)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:636)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:615)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:138)
    at com.novum.ideal.ExpandableListAdapter$LineupFragment.<init>(ExpandableListAdapter.java:149)
    at com.novum.ideal.ExpandableListAdapter$1.onClick(ExpandableListAdapter.java:126)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
```

i want to show that dialog from this class only.

how can i solved it?

Comment: you dont need the LineupFragment

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `new` operator on a subclass of `Activity`. The Activity itself has to go through all its lifecycle before you can use it as a valid `Context`, for your `DialogFragment`  in your case. Assuming you are instantiating your `ExpandableListAdapter` from a subclass of `FragmentActivity`, instead of keeping a reference to the `Context` you could a reference to the `FragmentActivity`/`Activity` you are using, and using this one, to retrive the an instance of the `supportFragmentManger` you need to show your `DialogFragment`.

Much better would be if you find a way to the the `Activity` that the `onClick` event occurred, leaving to it the responsibility to show the `DialogFragment` .

E.g

instead of having

```
private Context _context;
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context
```

you could have

```
private FragmentActivity mActivity;
public ExpandableListAdapter(FragmentActivity activity
```

and onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!mActivity.isFinishing()) {
      new MyAlertDialogFragment().show(mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Alert_Dialog");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this via any example? i am very confused in this.

Comment: which part is confusing you ?

Comment: How can i call that DialogFragment from the onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show it inside constructor. If you want to show dialog when activity is launched, do it inside `onCreate` method. Take a look at [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: i have added on `oncreate` but still it now shows the dialog box.